# Visual Studio local project setting best-practices?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do people commonly store local .settings files for their projects? For example, I have a solution for a web project in Mercurial. I have a data project containing my entities and repositories. My connection string is stored in Settings.settings and I'd like to have different sources depending on my location.

I was thinking I could simply move the file to Settings.settings.global and requiring anyone to change it when they clone my repo. Is there a better way of going about this? What are the best-practices for handling such things in Visual Studio?

One concern of mine with simply renaming the Settings.settings file containing my data source is that Visual Studio seems to automagically modify my app.config with the new values and I'm not sure how that will be handled if I force people to rename.

Comment: I believe VS 2010 handles this quite nicely. You can have multiple configuration files (release.web.config, qa.web.config) and choose which to run / deploy with.

Comment: While that is quite nice, I'd still like to allow for local config files. Each developer should be able to name their database whatever they want and have the connection string configured locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about `.settings` files, but for `.config` files and any other projects I'm using a file like `app.config.sample` which is included in the repository, along with a `.cmd` script which is creating the `app.config` file on run.

After cloning and running the `.cmd` script, any developer can customize the `app.config` as needed.

Off-topic: everyone I've asked advised me to keep the connection strings in `app.config`/`web.config`, but YMMV.

Some links:

- [ConnectionStrings Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx)
- [What is the best place to keep the Connection String](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/c71f6b0c-4f2d-470c-bb4a-38d1c867b76a)

Comment: So should I not be using the settings files? I'm a VS/.Net virgin so I'm basically learning this as I go on an existing project with no contact with the original developer. I think I'll look in to using app.config directly, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear on whether your organization is using revision control or not, but generally speaking, the `.settings` file committed to your revision control server contains some generic settings (or more specifically, testing or production settings). Then, each developer simply checks out the project, modifies `.settings` freely to suit their local configuration, and *never* submits the changes back to the revision control server. Everybody's happy!

Comment: As state in my original question, it woudl be great to have Settings.settings.global and simply force everyone to copy it to Settings.settings upon cloning (of course we use version control). However, as editing Settings.settings then causes VS to update app.config, I don't see how that would work. Can I forget about settings files and simply have multiple app.configs?